# How can I assign a specific item of an array to a specific item of another array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Dim arrInputData As Double() = New Double(intGlobalHistory) {}
Dim arrOutputData As Double() = New Double(0) {}

Dim arrInputArray As Double()() = New Double(intGlobalStepping)() {}
Dim arrOutputArray As Double()() = New Double(intGlobalStepping)() {}

For intStepping As Integer = 0 To intGlobalStepping
    For intHistory As Integer = (intGlobalHistory + 1) To 1 Step -1
        arrInputData(intHistory - 1) = dblSomeInputFactor + CDbl(intHistory)
    Next intHistory

    arrOutputData = New Double() {dblSomeOutputFactor + CDbl(intStepping)}

    arrInputArray(intStepping) = arrInputData
    arrOutputArray(intStepping) = arrOutputData
Next intStepping
```

However, when I assign a specific item in the arrInputArray to arrInputData:

```
    arrInputArray(intStepping) = arrInputData
```

all other items in the arrInputArray variable also change to reflect the new value in the arrInputData variable.

What am I doing wrong? I only want the specific item in arrInputArray changed, leaving all other items untouched.

Thanks!

Comment: That is because you are using `arrInputData` which is an array (a reference type) which gets overwritten with the next iteration. How about initializing `arrInputData` within the loop, same as what you are doing for `arrOutputData`?

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide an example, because I need all n items of arrInputData to contain information, filled in reverse order, which will then be assigned to a specific item in arrInputArray. Thanks!

Comment: You can do `arrInputData As Double() = New Double(intGlobalHistory) {}` within the for loop, to start with.

Comment: Did what you said, initializing `arrInputData` within the `intStepping` loop and it worked magic. You are the man. Can't mark as the answer because it's a comment, though... Thanks!

Comment: In any case, bear in mind that `arrInputArray(intStepping) = arrInputData` is perhaps not doing exactly what you want. For example: if after this line you write `arrInputArray(intStepping)(0) = 111.0` `arrInputData(0)` would also take the 111.0 value. That is: you are not copying the values from  `arrInputData` into  `arrInputArray(intStepping)`, but linking both arrays (any modification in one of them will also be applied to the other one). To avoid this situation, you should either copy the values or assign a new instance of the array (e.g., `arrInputArray(0) = arrInputData.Clone()`).

Comment: Yes... but since arrInputData now gets initialized on every iteration of intStepping, the problem is indeed solved. I tested it and Works flawlessly. Thanks!